# Splash not executing Javascript when proxy is used

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash

i am using scrapy_splash to crawl pages that requires js to retrieve proper content.

Everything is fine when I use SplashRequest without proxy settings, but when I put in proxy settings, the javascript would not render, giving me prejavascript html content which do not have the data I need.

Does anyone know how to solve this? I am sure the proxy ip are not blacklisted.

Comment: Can you share how you set the proxy and maybe your Splash script?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment,

But the short answer is because the proxy that you use don't allow to run javascript codes.

Please try another proxy that allow you run javascript code

Answer (score 0):

it turns out to be a slow proxy. I had to set wait to 10 to get result. Thanks for the help guys.